Understanding multidimensional quantum systems
I'm struggling to understand how to expand the formalism developed in class to multidimensional systems. I'm studying physics and we really didn't cover anything regarding separation of Hilbert spaces, tensor product and many thing that I feel like are necessary to understand what's going on, so it would be amazing if you could just tell me what to look for in order to fill some of my knowledge gaps in terms of the mathematical methods for quantum mechanics.
To give you a particular example, we are studying the system of two particles, $1$ and $2$. If I understood correctly from the internet, the Hilbert space containing the possible states for the complete system is obtained from $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$, although I know nothing about this operation.
Now, from this we should deduce that $|\psi \rangle \in \mathcal{H}\Rightarrow |\psi \rangle = |\psi_1 \rangle \otimes |\psi _2\rangle, \ |\psi _1\rangle \in \mathcal{H}_1 , \ |\psi _2\rangle \in \mathcal{H}_2   $. This allows to more properly understand operations like the action of an operator on $|\psi \rangle $, like $\hat{A}:\mathcal{H}_1 \to \mathcal{H}_1$ will have the following effect: $\hat{A} |\psi \rangle  = (\hat{A}|\psi _1\rangle) \otimes |\psi _2\rangle $. What I don't understand is how to represent the wave function for $|\psi \rangle $. By definition, I should have $\psi (\mathbf{r} ) = \langle\mathbf{r} | \psi \rangle $, where $|\mathbf{r}\rangle  = |x_1\rangle \otimes |x_2\rangle \otimes |x_3\rangle $. A little side note: both $\mathcal{H}_1,\mathcal{H}_2$ can be expressed as the Hilbert space associated to each dimension of the space, like $\mathcal{H}_1 = \mathcal{H}_{11}  \otimes \mathcal{H}_{12} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{13} $. Is this right? But if this was right, then I should have expressed the position ket $|r\rangle $ for $\mathcal{H}$ as $|\mathbf{r} _1\rangle \otimes |\mathbf{r} _2\rangle $, where again $|\mathbf{r} _1\rangle = |x_{11} \rangle \otimes |x_{12}\rangle \otimes |x_{13}\rangle  $, so:
$$|\mathbf{r} \rangle = \Big(|x_{11} \rangle \otimes |x_{12}\rangle \otimes |x_{13}\rangle\Big)\otimes\Big(|x_{21} \rangle \otimes |x_{22}\rangle \otimes |x_{23}\rangle\Big)$$
Is this the right way?
Back to the wave function: just for $\mathcal{H}_1$, $\psi _1 \equiv \langle\mathbf{r} _1 | \psi_1 \rangle $, right?  So
$$
\begin{align}
 \psi_1 (\mathbf{r}_1)  &= (\langle x_{11}| \otimes \langle x_{12}| \otimes \langle x_{13}| ) (|\psi_{11}\rangle \otimes |\psi_{12}\rangle \otimes |\psi_{13}\rangle  )\\
      &=\langle x_{11}|\psi_{11}\rangle \otimes \langle x_{12}|\psi_{12}\rangle \otimes \langle x_{13}|\psi_{13}\rangle \\
      &= \psi_{11}(x_{11}) \otimes \psi_{12} (x_{12}) \otimes \psi_{13}(x_{13})
\end{align}
$$
But then looking on the internet, people would write $\psi_1 = \psi_{11}\psi_{12} \psi_{13}$ using the ordinary product of the wave functions; why is it?
If the expression written above for $\psi_1$ is right, then $\psi  = \psi _1 \otimes \psi _2$ so that the hamiltonian $\hat{H}_1$ acting on $\mathcal{H}_1$ would behave like $\hat{H}_1 \psi = (\hat{H}_1\psi _1) \otimes \psi _2$, right?
If $E_1$ is the energy associated with $|\psi_1 \rangle $ and $E_2$ with $|\psi_2\rangle $, then it means that $\hat{H}\psi (\mathbf{r} ) = E_1 \psi_1 (\mathbf{r} _1) \otimes E_2 \psi_2 (\mathbf{r} _2) = (E_1+E_2)\big( \psi _1 (\mathbf{r} _1) \otimes \psi _2(\mathbf{r} _2)\big)$, right?
Thank you a lot in advance for any kind of help and sorry for my lack of knowledge.
NOTE: I hope the notation I used is clear enough to allow an easy understanding of all my questions; if you feel like I should modify something, don't hesitate to tell me.

Often, it can help to read other sources. As a student, I liked the book Quantum Physics by Le Bellac, chapter 6 (but I cannot claim that I remember enough to directly answer your questions).

@C.Hamster Thank you, I'll give it a look. Since I miss a lot of important math behind QM and I'm not planning on understanding everything right now (I'll have a much more in depth course in the future) I preferred asking here to see if I was on the right track because I feel like going through a textbook would just make things harder for me (since I'm on a really strict schedule for my exams). Nevertheless, I will try, thank you again!

This script contains on pages 8 and 9 something not too abstract. In short: when the single-particle Hilbert spaces are ${\cal H},{\cal K}$ both equal to $L^2(Y,\mu)$ ($\mu,\nu$ two $\sigma$-finite measures on $X$ resp. $Y$) then for two "wave functions" $f\in{\cal H},g\in{\cal K}$ their tensor product is simply
$$
(f\otimes g)(x,y)=f(x)g(y)
$$
which is a function in $L^2(X\times Y,\mu\times\nu)\,.$ Thus, this product
space may be identified with ${\cal H}\otimes{\cal K}\,.$
I find it astonishing that you are sitting in a physics class where this was not mentioned.
What is now important is to know when a quantum state in ${\cal H}\otimes{\cal K}$ describes two entangled states, or two states that can be considered as separable into two quantum states where a measurement on
one of the states has no effect on the other state. In short:
$$
|\psi\rangle=\frac{f\otimes g+u\otimes v}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
is typically an entangled state, and $|\psi\rangle=f\otimes g$ is always a separable product state.
Your post contains a lot of questions and misconceptions which I cannot all address in this answer. The first that strikes me is that
you think of $|\mathbf{r}\rangle$ (which must be an eigenstate of the
position operator of one particle in $\mathbb R^3$) as
$$
|\mathbf{r}\rangle=|x_1\rangle\otimes|x_2\rangle\otimes|x_3\rangle\,.
$$
This could formally even be true but I don't think it contributes to
the physics. It is better to think of $|\phi\rangle,|\psi\rangle$ both being
in ${\cal H}=L^2(\mathbb R^3)$ each describing another particle and
$$
|\phi\rangle\otimes|\psi\rangle\in L^2(\mathbb R^3\times\mathbb R^3)={\cal H}\otimes{\cal H}
$$
describing the system consisting of the two particles.
